# One symbol - one meaning?

Tags: c++, programming-practices

It's well known recomendations that:

- 1) **class or function should have one responsibility**
- 2) **variable should not be reused in different contexts**

We can generalize this recomendations to general rule:

**Symbol should have one meaning.**

Then, for example in crossplatform development is often used similar code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32

    class CFoo {
        /* ... */
    };

#elif _LINUX

    class CFoo {
        /* ... */
    };

#endif
```

With this code, when you later refer to `CFoo`, it can have three meanings:

- `CFoo` as Win32 platform specific class
- `CFoo` as Linux platform specific class
- `CFoo` as crossplatform class

So, when you use `CFoo` symbol somewhere, its not exactly clear which `CFoo` it is.

Violates similar code "essence" of recomendations 1) or 2) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A question about the word "meaning" should not be discussed in meaningless terms like `CFoo`.

Lets make a better example:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    class MyUsbDriver {
        /* ... a public API to access a special USB devcice.. */
        /* ... internal implementation: Windows sepecific.. */
    };
#elif _LINUX
    class MyUsbDriver {
        /* ... exactly the same API as in the WIN32 version.. */
        /* ... internal implementation: Linux sepecific.. */
    };
#endif
```

That way you create an *abstraction* for an Usb-Driver, so for the code actually *using* that class **both variants have the same meaning** - from that point of view. Ideally, for the calling code, there should be no visible difference between the two classes.

Note that in C++, you have much better means for creating such abstractions than using the preprocessor. For such a situation it would probably be preferable to make `MyUsbDriver` an abstract interface class, with derived classes `MyUsbDriverWin32` and `MyUsbDriverLinux`. However, you will probably have to encapsulate those two derived classes in `#ifdef` blocks, since otherwise you might not be able to compile each class in the environment it was not designed for.

What you should avoid is something like

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    class MyUsbDriver {
        /* ... a public API to access a special USB devcice.. */
    };
#elif _LINUX
    class MyUsbDriver {
        /* ... a completely different API as in the WIN32 version.. */
        /* ... or (worse): a similar looking API, with a different behaviour  */
    };
#endif
```

that would be somehow similar to "reusing the same variable in different contexts twice".